# How to print only the product barcode label in Odoo? How to change the default size of the paper?

Tags: xml, report, odoo, qweb

I am creattng a report to print a barcode label.

My template try to print the whole page, but I need a specia page side: `width = 35mm` and `height = 11mm`.

So how and where can I change the default product label report template and make changes? I need to print only the label as pdf.

Comment: You need to use a custom paperformat: Settings > Report > Paper format

Comment: And you should use the appropiate layout, if I have time I will write an answer for you later

Answer (score 1):

The report template with the barcode, this example is uses a qrcode, but you can change it to adapt it to your needs. You can add some styles as well:

```xml
<template id="report_label_style" inherit_id="website_report.layout">
    <xpath expr="//style" position="after">
        <style type="text/css">
            .example_class {
                display: block;
                width: 228px;
                height: 103px;
            }
        </style>
    </xpath>
</template>

<template id="report_label">
    <t t-call="report.html_container">
        <t t-foreach="docs" t-as="o">
            <div class="page">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="example_class">
                        <t t-set="qr_src">/report/barcode/?type=QR&amp;value=<t t-esc="o.qr_string" />&amp;width=600&amp;height=600</t>
                        <img t-att-src="'%s' % qr_src"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </t>
    </t>
</template>
```

The paperformat definition. You will see the paperformat if you go to: **Settings > Report > Paper forma**

```xml
<record id="paperformat_label_example" model="report.paperformat">
    <field name="name">Paperformat Example</field>
    <field name="default" eval="True"/>
    <field name="format">custom</field>
    <field name="page_height">23</field>
    <field name="page_width">50</field>
    <field name="orientation">Portrait</field>
    <field name="margin_top">0</field>
    <field name="margin_bottom">0</field>
    <field name="margin_left">0</field>
    <field name="margin_right">0</field>
    <field name="header_line" eval="False"/>
    <field name="header_spacing">0</field>
    <field name="dpi">80</field>
</record>
```

The report action, this creates the needed record in the model `ir_act_report_xml`:

```xml
<report id="action_report_label"
        model="model.name"
        report_type="qweb-pdf"
        name="module_name.report_label"
        file="module_name.report_label"
        string="Label" />
```

Here I associate the paperformat to the report:

```xml
<record id="module_name.action_report_label" model="ir.actions.report.xml">
    <field name="paperformat_id" ref="module_name.paperformat_label_example"/>
</record>
```